# Cluster creation with different instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We are in situation where we need to create a AWS ECS cluster with different instance type using aws ecs-cli commands. Is it possible to create a ECS cluster with different instance type using ECS cli commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can only create a customised Task Definition with desired vCPUs and Memory but to create a customised ECS Cluster is not possible i suppose.
Thanks.